# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException while trying to pass a closure as a parameter

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy and am trying to pass a closure as a parameter to a method , below is my code , I am using Groovy 2.4

```
class Test
{
    def testMethod()
    {
        def cl = {a,b -> println "a = "+${a}+" b = "+${b}}
        testClosure(cl);
    }

    def testClosure(closure)
    {
        closure(5,2);
    }
}
```

I am getting the below exception when i am trying to execute it ,

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 
   com.gr.practice.Test.$() is applicable for argument types:
   (com.gr.practice.Test$_testMethod_closure1$_closure2) values:
   [com.gr.practice.Test$_testMethod_closure1$_closure2@3e92efc3]
Possible solutions: 
   is(java.lang.Object), 
   any(),
   any(groovy.lang.Closure),
   use([Ljava.lang.Object;),
   wait(), 
   dump()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
   com.gr.practice.Test.$() is applicable for argument types:
   (com.gr.practice.Test$_testMethod_closure1$_closure2) values:
   [com.gr.practice.Test$_testMethod_closure1$_closure2@3e92efc3]
Possible solutions: 
   is(java.lang.Object),
   any(),
   any(groovy.lang.Closure),
   use([Ljava.lang.Object;),
   wait(),
   dump()
    at com.gr.practice.Test$_testMethod_closure1.doCall(Test.groovy:10)
    at com.gr.practice.Test.testClosure(Test.groovy:16)
    at com.gr.practice.Test$testClosure$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.gr.practice.Test.testMethod(Test.groovy:11)
    at com.gr.practice.Test$testMethod.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.gr.practice.main.run(main.groovy:7)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Could anyone please help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't pass closures in groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709775/cant-pass-closures-in-groovy)

Comment: HI you can mark this as fixed , the problem was i was the ${variable} should be within the quotes.

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson I don't think this is a duplicate of the issue you referenced.  These are 2 separate problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `println "a = "+${a}+" b = "+${b}`.  You probably want this:

```
println "a = ${a} b = ${b}"
```

Or:

```
println "a = " + a + " b = " + b
```

(the former is a better idea)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jeff , although doing the same fixes it in Intellig Idea but facing the same problem in eclipse with groovy-eclipse plugin , below is the improvised code , `def static main(String[] args)
 {
 
  def cl = { a,b -> println "a = ${a} and b = ${b}"}
  testClosure(cl)
 }

 private def testClosure(closure)
 {
  closure(5,2)
 }` Do you have a clue why this might be happening ?

Comment: `println "a = ${a} b = ${b}"` is valid Groovy code, regardless of what IDE you are using.  If the IDE complains about it for some reason, that is an IDE bug.  That is valid code.